# Save the view of a UIScrollView

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview, controls, save, segment

I am building an app where part of it allows you to scroll through different images to overlay. I have a segmented control to make a sort of layering system where each segment allows you to scroll through the images again and build up layers. For some reason first image always sticks and when I return to a layer, the view is reset to its original position but also saves the last position?

Here is my code.

```
- (void)layerControl
{
UIScrollView *scroll = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
scroll.pagingEnabled = YES;
NSInteger viewCount = 8;
for (int i = 0; i < viewCount; i++) {
    CGFloat yOrigin = i * self.view.frame.size.width;
    UIImageView *filterViewOverlay = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(yOrigin, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
    [filterViewOverlay setImage:[filterManager objectAtIndex:i]];
    [scroll addSubview:filterViewOverlay];
    //[filterViewOverlay release];
}
scroll.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width * viewCount, self.view.frame.size.height);
[self.view addSubview:scroll];
[scroll autorelease];

//Determine the current filter in view of the scroll view
CGFloat pageWidth = scroll.frame.size.width;
int cFilter = floor((scroll.contentOffset.x - pageWidth / 2) / pageWidth) + 1;
currentFilter = cFilter;

}



//Method to add a filter to the page
- (void)addFilter:(id)sender
{
UISegmentedControl *filterController = (UISegmentedControl *)sender;

switch ([filterController selectedSegmentIndex])
{
    case 0: self.layerControl;

    case 1: self.layerControl;

    case 2: self.layerControl;

    case 3: self.layerControl;

    case 4: self.layerControl;

    case 5: self.layerControl;

    default: NULL;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like maybe every time you call self.layerControl you are creating a new UIScrollView on the view.
So the old one is still there and in the old position, but you've added another one.

Perhaps store a reference to each UIScrollView and at the beginning of layerControl grab the scrollview for the given index.

So:

```
- (void)layerControl:(NSInteger)index {
   UIScrollView *scrollView = nil;
   switch (index) {
      case (0): scrollView = self.scrollView1;
      /* Repeat for 1 - 6 */
   }

   if (scrollView == nil) {
      // Do the creation of the scrollview here
   }
```

Then in your addFilter method call:

```
[self layerControl:[filterController selectedSegmentIndex]]
```

rather than the big switch statement.

As an aside, it's not a great idea to call methods with dot syntax like you have with all those self.layerControl calls.
You should leave dot syntax for times when you're accessing a synthesized property.

Comment: Okay thanks very much! I new to objective-C programming so I will keep your .dot syntax recommendation in mind. Thanks again!

Comment: Can I just ask the case switches 'Case 0: scroll = self.scroll1' - what does 'scroll1' reference? Cheers

Comment: self.scroll1 just references a retained property that you would define in the header of that class.
You'd have scroll1, scroll2... scroll6 and each would hold a reference to the scrollview for each layer.

Comment: Ahh I see.. I have tried that, but nothing happens? Sorry to be such a pain! Cheers

Comment: Try debugging to ensure that your layers are being set up when you enter the - (void)layerControl:(NSInteger)index method (after the code that I suggested).

Basically that code is there to ensure you always have a reference to the layers you've created, so that when you go back to the layer you have a handle to it.

Comment: There is one more issue. Now whenever I click a new layer and switch back, the image defaults to the original and the image that was previously set is still there?

Comment: It sounds like maybe you aren't actually assigning your new layers to the scroll1.. properties? So a new one is getting created each time.

Comment: Make sure the nil check block does somehting like
if (scrollView == nil) {
      // Do the creation of the scrollview here
      self.scroll1 = [[[UIScrollView alloc] ini...] autorelease];
   }

You'll need to find a way to assign to the right property though (not just scroll1).

Comment: The code is as you said but I moved the code in your if statement above the switch and removed the if because nothing appeared before that

Comment: Also, for some reason, when the scroll view works, I cannot hide the navigation bar or toolbar by tapping using the methods I created and they do work when its not there? cheers

Comment: I have defined the scrollView1,2,3 etc in the .h file: UIScrollView *scroll1 and then @property (monatomic, retain) UIScrollView *scroll1 and also synthesised it in the .m file... Im really stuck now :S

Comment: Hi again, when i try to load the current UIScrollView it creates a new one.... Does anyone know why?